# jQuery tooltip and drop-down (combo-box): Issue in IE 9

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

In IE 9, if I apply tool tip on drop down, it not allowed me to select any option.

```
<select title="my tooltip dropdown">
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<select title="my tooltip dropdown">
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
</select>

$(document).tooltip()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmSEE/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll work if you wrap the `select` with a `div` or `span`.

e.g.

```
<div title="my tooltip dropdown">
<select>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
<option>1234</option>
</select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmSEE/5/